# Where's 'in-law' in mother-in-law from?

Tags: etymology, kinship-terms

I've read that it's somehow connected with the Canon Law, but I'm not sure. I'm really interested in finding the answer.

Answer (score 17):

It comes from Middle English *modyr in lawe*.  As far as I understand it, the term was first used in the 14th or 15th century.  The idea behind it is that your mother-in-law has the same rights and duties as your biological mother and is given these rights and duties by the legal pact of marriage.

Comment: @Juls if the answer provided by Andrew solves your doubts, you should accept it. :)

Comment: Additional information: For the reason Andrew gives behind the meaning of the word, the term was also used to refer to one's step-mother. In general, the term thus referred to a woman who was not your biological mother, but who had the legal rights and responsibilities of same.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I was thinking that if you could include some reference, especially for the part of the first usage, your answer would be greatly improved! Just a thought, since it's already good. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's the OED etymology:

> A phrase appended to names of
>   relationship, as father, mother,
>   brother, sister, son, etc., to
>   indicate that the relationship is not
>   by nature, but in the eye of the Canon
>   Law, with reference to the degrees of
>   affinity within which marriage is
>   prohibited. These forms can be traced
>   back to the 14th century. Formerly
>   -in-law was also used to designate those relationships which are now
>   expressed by step-, e.g. son-in-law =
>   step-son, father-in-law = step-father;
>   this, though still locally or vulgarly
>   current, is now generally considered a
>   misuse.
>
> <sub>source: “-in-law.” *The Oxford English Dictionary*. 2nd ed. 1989. *OED Online.* Oxford University Press. 15 June 2011 <[dictionary.oed.com](http://dictionary.oed.com)></sub>

Essentially, you cannot marry anyone related to you "in-law" because Canon Law treats them identically to an actual brother, sister, etc.

Comment: Oh, that's actually what i was looking for..can you pls tell me the source of your info? i just need it for my grad paper:) thnx so much!

Comment: “-in-law.” _The Oxford English Dictionary_. 2nd ed. 1989. _OED Online_. 
Oxford University Press. 15 June 2011 <http://dictionary.oed.com/>.

Comment: again thank you, you've practically saved my life :)

Answer (score 4):

The usage of "in-laws" came a long way, from [Anglo-Norman:](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O27-inlaw.html)

> in-law XIX. sb. use of phr. denoting connection by marriage, e.g. brother-in-law (XIII), father-in-law (XIV); after AN. en ley, OF. en loi (de mariage) ‘in law (of marriage)

It is just to denote that this "brother" is only a brother due to marriage, and is therefore a brother by law, not by birth.

Comment: should that be "by law, not by birth"?

Comment: haha! I'm making mistakes everywhere, and @Ben Voigt is picking them up for me! :)

Comment: I had nothing better to do while eating pizza.  It was even a Canadian-bacon pizza.  Coincidence?

Comment: Ironic...Ironic? Is that how I should use ironic? i'm so confused now!

Comment: Just think, someone eating pizza made out of one of my cousins...Did you answer the question on pizza fractions?

Comment: @Ham: I did not, although I did read it, I agreed with an existing answer.  "twenty-nine sixths" seems like a great improvement for prose.  And yes, I believe eating Canadian-bacon (which amazingly many pizza parlors will simply substitute with ham) on my pizza while commenting on your answers qualifies as ironic.

Answer (score -2):

The term was first used in 14 or 15 century to indicate that the relationship is not by nature but in eye of the canon laws

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.