# "Son-in-law" or "son-by-law"

Tags: meaning, etymology, kinship-terms

Why is there *in* in *-in-law* instead of *by* or something similar? Simon Jester, in [his answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/wheres-in-law-in-mother-in-law-from/29820#29820), quotes the Oxford English Dictionary which says that it originally applied to step-relatives rather than those now considered in-laws, but I still don't know why we use *son-in-law* instead of *son-by-law*.

Comment: I know it's similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/wheres-in-law-in-mother-in-law-from, but I think it's different because that question asks where the phrase comes from, and I'm asking what it means.

Comment: We commonly use *both* prepositions "in" and "by" with "law". Come to that, we also have set phrases like [Attorney at law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attorney_at_law). I don't think it's meaningful to ask why we happen to have settled on "in" for the "related by marriage" constructions. We have to use one or the other preposition, but it could just as well have been "by" or "at".

Comment: @FumbleFingers And given that *-in-law* is from c.1300 we may never know. Incidentally, *bylaw*, local ordinance, is late 13c.

Comment: @Hugo: and [byelaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byelaws_in_the_United_Kingdom), I suppose. Which is how I'd normally spell it, but maybe there's a UK/US difference there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm from the UK and would normally spell it *byelaw* as well, but was etymologically distracted. This *-by* is like that in Grimsby and Forsby. And I suppose also the word *by*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Definitely a UK/US difference. It's always a *bylaw* in the US.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That would be consistent with the general principle that (largely down to Webster) US spelling tends to discard pointless/misleading anachronisms in spelling that we Brits just can't seem to shake. Personally, I always think of *byelaws* themselves as a bit anachronistic, in that most of our laws now come from central government (or indeed, the nascent *European* government in Brussels). The archaic spelling kinda suits the referent!

Comment: Different words are used for cousins (at least in the US). My wife's cousins are my _cousins-by-marriage_ not my cousins-in-law.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, regarding meaningfulness, I just wanted to know; it's not useful to me in any way. Regarding "we have to use one or the other preposition," that's my question: why did "in" fall into the pool of prepositions that made sense?

Comment: @zpletan: I didn't mean your *question* was meaningless, just that it's unlikely we could hope to establish exactly why of the three prepositions that we use to mean "in the context of" for "law", it just so happens that we've settled on "in" for the "related by marriage" meaning. As to why *in, by,* and *at* are valid prepositions for this purpose in the first place, it seems to me many prepositions are inherently "slippery", and don't have very precise meanings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, OK. I hope I didn't come across as offended or offensive—that certainly wasn't my aim, but I think I could have been construed that way. I looked up "in" (I should have done that a *long* time ago) and I understand now about it's being "slippery."

Comment: @zpletan: I don't know if the problem is so bad in other languages, but English has many, many expressions where it seems almost arbitrary which preposition we use, but in fact native speakers overwhelmingly stick with one particular usage. Non-natives can always get by and be understood if they use a "wrong" one, because there's so little meaning in the preposition. But when you've not been born and brought up hearing the "right" ones, it's an awful lot to learn if you want to be word-perfect.

Answer (score 0):

*In law* is a common enough collocation. The OED records 898 examples. Its use in describing relatives is merely a particular case.

Comment: I don't subscribe to the OED, and don't really want to just to know the answer. Could you please post some examples of its use that do not describe relatives?

Comment: Here are five selected at random: ‘Co-executors . . . are regarded in law as an individual person’; ‘This enclose, when justifiable, is called in law approving’; ‘which sufficient estate is in law called assets’; ‘What do you mean in law by exposing his person?’; ‘The goods were in a vendue store, a common market, a public place known and established in law.’

Comment: The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 1507 entries for ‘in law’. You can see them all here: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/.

Comment: The Corpus of Contemporary American English also has 2332 entries for ‘by law’.

Comment: I'm not surprised, but the two will be used to mean different things, or at the very least be used in different contexts.